# Scrolltofixed + site menu + wordpress issue

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Having an issue involving a site in development.  One page has a wordpress blog integrated into it.  I have scrolltofixed running, but the issue is that on the page with the blog, the menu has a greater height then my other pages (no wordpress).  (cloned the twenty eleven theme)

Blog page with "thicker" menu -> http://mandysaile.com/blog/

vs

"Regular" page http://mandysaile.com/getintouch/

I assume the issue is a css conflict somewhere, but can't track it down.  Tried using firebug to figure it out, but no joy as of yet.  The menu being used is not via wordpress (as only the blog page is a wordpress page).  Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In your blog you have this:

```
body{font: 300 15px/1.625 "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;}
```

which is not in your original page.

You can solve it in 2 ways:

1) add this code to your original page (or remove from blog)
2) if you need to keep this font declaration as is for any reason, simply change `#menu li a` to this:

```
#menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    font-family: "amazonebt";
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #3F5B5F;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that is a fast response!  I changed the padding line to eliminate the top padding as suggested, but the menu bars remain different on the 2 pages (only a big narrower).  I removed the body{font: 300 etc... line from the wordpress styles.css and no luck there either.  I was hovering around this line also (thanks to firebug), but can't get anything to work.